# Uneven inner margins in mdframed?

Tags: mdframed

EDIT: Solution below.

I can't really find an answer to this. I am trying to make a box using mdframed for important notes. I noticed as I started writing that the left inner margin and the right inner margin are uneven. [image]

As you can see, the left side has an inner margin that is accurate, but the right side has a margin that appears to be negative by default.

Naturally I could increase the right margin by X amount, but I think something isn't working as it should, so I would like to know what I am missing. This is a copy of the two sections

```
\newcounter{notecount}[subsection]
\newenvironment{note} {\refstepcounter{notecount}
  \mdfsetup{
    innertopmargin=5pt,
    innerbottommargin=5pt,
    innerleftmargin=0.5cm,
    innerrightmargin=0.5cm,
    leftmargin=0.5cm,
    rightmargin=0.5cm,
    splitbottomskip=0pt,
    splittopskip=0pt,
    topline=true,
    leftline=true,
    bottomline=true,
    rightline=true,
    linewidth=1pt,
    innerlinewidth=0pt,
    font=\normalfont,
    frametitle={\textbf{Important Note \thenotecount}},
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=5pt,
    frametitlebelowskip=5pt,
    linecolor=gray,
    innerlinecolor=gray,
    middlelinecolor=gray,
    outerlinecolor=gray,
    align=left,
  }
  \begin{mdframed}
}
{\end{mdframed}}
```

This is the content

```
\subsubsection{Provision Process}
\begin{note}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum ultricies purus, volutpat euismod dui faucibus sit amet. Curabitur luctus elit ac dapibus pharetra. Morbi sed leo iaculis, pretium magna ut, mollis elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis risus eu felis sagittis elementum id quis libero. Sed volutpat augue eget dolor feugiat porttitor. Morbi lacus felis, congue a purus non, imperdiet dignissim diam. Donec tempor ex viverra dolor interdum sollicitudin. Curabitur aliquam, metus volutpat faucibus egestas, nisi nibh fermentum purus, id elementum lorem ipsum sit amet lorem. Etiam consequat lorem quis sem luctus, eu viverra neque fermentum. Quisque laoreet diam sed lectus vestibulum condimentum. Suspendisse ac imperdiet mi.
\end{note}
```

---

Solution: raggedright was on for the document. I removed ragged2e and replaced any alignment with flushleft and flushright.

Comment: If I run this in a minimal example, using `article` documentclass, I get the correct result. So it appears there may be something else in your document that causes this. Please make a MWE that shows the problem. It looks like there is a `\raggedright` thrown in somewhere.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I don't have a \raggedright anywhere, but I did comment out the `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` and the result looks normal now. Good call, now I at least know where to look. 

EDIT: Looks like document is whats causing this issue. I just read up on the document option and it appears to use ragged right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in edit

Comment: I would also like to mark this as solved, but I am not sure how to go about doing it.